# testing a react form with pure Jest library (no enzyme) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Currently I am testing a react form with only jest.
My intention is to:

1. test that submit button is clicked
2. test that submit button is called with forms entered data

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const CustomerForm = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        fname: "",
        lname: ""
    })

const handleChange = (e)=> {
    // console.log(e);
    setForm({...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}

const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.handleSubmit(form);
}
 return(
        <form id="customer" onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" value="firstName" id="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" value="lastName" id="lastName" onChange={handleChange} />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    );
}
```

```
 it('check for form is clicked', () => {
        .......
    });

    it('form is submitted with entered data', () => {
        ......
    });
```

I am completely lost as it is the most simplest scenario and I barely know how to test these two basic conditions.
Please suggest how to do this tests so that I can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use Enzyme for the testing. a recommendation could be to render the component and then with querySelector seach for the specific element you want trigger the event. You need to import
"react-dom" and "@testing-library/react";

example:

```
let container;

//With beforeEach will create a new div for each test in the file and adding it.
beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

it("check for form is clicked", () => {
  act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<CustomerForm />, container);
  });

  //querySelector to find the specific DOM element to want to trigger the event.
  const firstName = container.querySelector("#firstName");
  const button = container.querySelector("button");
  firstName.change();
  button.click()
  expect(firstName.value).toBe('')
});
```

Here the doc for more information:https://es.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html

Hope it helps you or least give you an a idea